# Recursive Fibonacci in Rust with memoization

Tags: recursion, rust, fibonacci-sequence, memoization

I'm trying to come up with an "elegant" way of calculating Fibonacci for number in Rust, using recursion and memoization (self-imposed requirements).

This is what I have so far:

```
fn fib(n: usize, memo: &mut [Option<usize>]) -> usize {
    memo[n].map(|v| v).unwrap_or_else(|| {
        let result = {
            if n > 1 {
                fib(n - 1, memo) + fib(n - 2, memo)
            } else {
                1
            }
        };
        memo[n] = Some(result);
        result
    })
}

fn main() {
    let number = 46;
    let mut memo: Vec<Option<usize>> = vec![None; number + 1];
    println!("{}", fib(number, &mut memo));
}
```

My cache in this implementation is just a slice of optional values, if the position contains `Some(x)` that's a cache hit, otherwise, in a closure, compute the value, passing the cache along, and just before returning the value save it as a `Some(v)` in the cache.

I figured that setting up a cache this way would make writes faster, since the memory is already allocated.

Can it be made faster? Or cleaner/more readable?

Comment: `map()` isn't necessary.

Comment: 0 is not necessary, [`std::num::NonZeroUsize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.NonZeroUsize.html) will save you space

Comment: @Stargateur My bad, that `map()` call is leftover code from a previous version of the code. Interestingly, Clippy completely overlooks the useless `map()`.

Comment: *Clippy completely overlooks the useless `map()`* — there are actually times where `map(|x| x)` *isn't* a no-op, surprisingly.

Comment: @Shepmaster Can you expand more on which cases `map(|x| x)` is useful or not? Or does it deserves a full question in StackOverflow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. There's no reason to ascribe a type to `memo`.
2. Don't expose the memoization logic outside the call. Instead, create a shim function that creates the memoization vector for you.
3. You can then define the memoized function inside the shim function, preventing people from accidentally calling it.
4. Since the `memo` variable isn't used after the top-most recursive call, you can just pass in the reference directly, without creating a variable.
5. As mentioned in the comments, the `map(|x| x)` call is not needed here.
6. Write *some* kind of automated tests.

```
fn fib(number: usize) -> usize {
    fn fib_memo(n: usize, memo: &mut [Option<usize>]) -> usize {
        memo[n].unwrap_or_else(|| {
            let result = {
                if n > 1 {
                    fib_memo(n - 1, memo) + fib_memo(n - 2, memo)
                } else {
                    1
                }
            };
            memo[n] = Some(result);
            result
        })
    }

    fib_memo(number, &mut vec![None; number + 1])
}

fn main() {
    let number = 46;
    let r = fib(number);
    println!("{}", r);
    assert_eq!(2971215073, r);
}
```

That being said, I'd point out that this memoized version of Fibonacci is not the most efficient — you don't need to keep every previous value forever. Instead, check out numerous ways of being more efficient:

- [Implement a generic Fibonacci sequence in Rust without using Copy trait](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/130042/32521)
- [How to swap two variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31798737/155423)
- [How to avoid excessive cloning in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40965230/155423)
- [Is it possible to use a fold with a Vec?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27760022/155423)

One possible implementation of that:

```
fn fib(n: usize) -> usize {
    fn fib_memo(n: usize, memo: &mut [usize; 2]) -> usize {
        let [a, b] = *memo;
        let c = a + b;
        if n == 0 {
            c
        } else {
            *memo = [b, c];
            fib_memo(n - 1, memo)
        }
    }

    if n < 2 {
        1
    } else {
        fib_memo(n - 2, &mut [1, 1])
    }
}
```

Or a non-recursive variant:

```
fn fib(n: usize) -> usize {
    if n < 2 {
        1
    } else {
        let mut memo = [1, 1];
        let mut n = n - 2;

        loop {
            let [a, b] = memo;
            let c = a + b;

            if n == 0 {
                return c;
            }

            memo = [b, c];
            n -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I still not familiar with what (functions/structs/traits/imports?) can be nested inside functions/blocks in Rust, is it all the same, and it only affects visibility? But yeah, the "shim" function is how I would do it in general (I also know it as a "portal" function).

Comment: Of course (at least regarding Fibonacci) recursion is not great, I just wanted to learn more about Rust (and memory/references) using that constraint. Thanks so much for the links!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably way late already. But I sort of preferred handling a memoized solution to fibonacci in rust using the hashMap.

```
pub fn memoized_fib(num: usize) -> usize {
    struct Fibi {
        memo: HashMap<usize, usize>,
    }

    impl Fibi {
        fn new(num: usize) -> Fibi {
            return Fibi {
                memo: HashMap::with_capacity(num),
            };
        }

        fn get_fibi(&mut self, num: usize) -> usize {
            if num <= 2 {
                return 1;
            }

            if !self.memo.contains_key(&num) {
                let fibi_one = self.get_fibi(num - 1);
                let fibi_two = self.get_fibi(num - 2);

                self.memo.entry(num).or_insert(fibi_one + fibi_two);
            }
            return *self.memo.get(&num).unwrap();
        }
    }

    let mut result = Fibi::new(num);
    return result.get_fibi(num);
}
```